# Get data from a form back to back end

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, http

I have a java Spring Boot application in one project and Angular in another(2 different ports).
What I want to do is create a form in the angular project where the user can enter a date into the text field and when the user clicks on the find button , the date string variable should be sent to the backend java program using http post services via a REST api(no databases).
what Ive done so far is ,
Ive created a basic form in html and I initialized an array list(**dateCheck**) in java to get the date from the client to the backend. I've a very little knowledge on angular as Im very new . It would be great if you could check my code and guide me . Thank you.

----Java code to get data----

```
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200")
@PostMapping("/dateReq")
public ArrayList<String> getDates(){
    return PremiereLeagueManager.dateCheck;

}
```

**------Angular------------**

**----app.component.ts-------**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import{HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'
export interface PeriodicElement {}

 @Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
 })
 export class AppComponent {
  title: any;
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  onSubmit(data){
  this.http.post('http://localhost:8083/dateReq',data)
  .subscribe((data)=>{
    console.log("result",data)
  })
 }
}
```

**-------app.component.html--------**

```
<form #datePost="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(datePost.value)" >
<input type="text" name="date" ngModel placeholder="12/12/2012">
<button type="submit">Find</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `@DateTimeFormat` annotation on your backend to recive date from request

and use date pattern you need

```
 @CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200")
 @PostMapping("/dateReq")
 public ArrayList<String> getDates(@RequestParam("date") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy") Date date) {
        // ...
  }
```

Here more information https://www.baeldung.com/spring-date-parameters